# Error after Updating play-services "Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabo"

Tags: android, compilation, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I updated play-services dependencies to version 15.0.0 and also added play-services-safetynet to my app.gradle. After that i always get

> Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabo
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabo, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

when building the app. here is my app.build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.0.1"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "XXXXXXX-$versionName")
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper:urlimageviewhelper:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:15.0.0'
    compile 'org.kefirsf:kefirbb:1.5'
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I didn't actually update to version 15.0.0, was already on it, and suddenly started getting this (although it seems like something were downloaded.. as if someone pushed a bad version...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my case, I had to update Firebase from version 15.0.0 to 15.0.2 in project's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2"
    ...
}
```

And then in app's build.gradle I had to update google-services from 3.1.1 to 3.3.0:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
    ...
}
```

Comment: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1' should be classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'

Comment: React-Native Warning*, `google-services:3.3.0` may fail Gradle sync. Use `3.2.1` in this case. 
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50325145/1762493

Answer (score 6):

You can try using the exact version number following this link:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions

> SDK Update - May 2, 2018 - Firebase Android SDKs now have independent version numbers, allowing for more frequent, flexible updates.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem today. Google comes with the new release on 02 may 2018.

Please go to the link and set the version no according to the doc:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20180502

for e.g.

Firebase Core com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Try using firebase libs version `15.0.2` or higher instead. Also clean your project `./gradlew clean`, as well as kill your Gradle daemons: `./gradlew --stop`

Answer (score 0):

1.Update all the firebase libs according to [this release page](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20180502).

2.Update google location and google map service to 15.0.1.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
```