# Program type already present: android.support.v7.util.AsyncListUtil$1

Tags: java, android, mobile

I recognize that there are several "Program type already present" questions out there already, but none seem to fully address (or help with) my situation:
I am getting "Program type already present: android.support.v7.util.AsyncListUtil$1" - I think this started when I update from exoplayer 2.7. to exoplayer 2.8

```
Program type already present: android.support.v7.util.AsyncListUtil$1
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v7.util.AsyncListUtil$1, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

At one point, Android Studio stopped complaining about AsynListUtil but began saying the same thing about Annotations.AnyRef

build.gradle pasted below.  Any help would be appreciated.  I have resolved any dependency/library conflicts flagged by Android Studio, and have done "Tools > Clean Project", "Tools > Rebuild Project", and "File > Invalidate Caches / Restart"

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'sotdaakey'
            keyPassword 'sotdaamerc'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/Doug/AndroidStudioProjects/SpeakerDayAA_fromscratch/local files/keystores/android.jks')
            storePassword 'sotdmerc'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.hintonworx.speakerdayaa'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 8
        versionName '1.6'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "recovery"
    productFlavors {
        aa {
            //applicationId 'com.hintonworx.speakerday.aa'
            applicationId 'com.hintonworx.speakerdayaa'
            // must use this because AA version was originally published this way
            testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        }
        na {
            applicationId 'com.hintonworx.speakerday.na'
            testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    // make customtabs 27.1.1 explicit, because play-services-ads:15.0.1 uses an earlier version
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-mediasession:2.8.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-ima:2.8.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I began to think it may be Firebase related, as per: [Android Studio- Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146640/android-studio-program-type-already-present-com-google-android-gms-internal-me)

So removed the Firebase dependency and references in my code, but still get:

```
Program type already present: android.support.annotation.AnyRes
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.annotation.AnyRes, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  In my case, I found android-support-v4-23.1.1 and android-support-v7-recyclerview-23.1.1 in the /libs folder.  They hadn't been causing me problems before updating exoplayer and Firebase.  Removing those allowed me to compile and deploy again without errors.  Not exactly sure how they had gotten there in the first place, but I think they were left from the library package install of an ad mediation network.