# Program type already present: com.google.firebase.auth.zza

Tags: android, firebase

I really don't know what's going on, I've searched everything and nothing worked. If someone could help me, I would really appreciate. I change all dependencies and libraries to try to solve it, but nothing worked.

This error occurs after I change API 27 to 28 of my project.

if I change any dependency version then chances to occur more error in my project.

Here is build.gradle app

```
      android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.letslocate"
            minSdkVersion 18
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


       implementation 'com.github.ar-android:DrawRouteMaps:1.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Here is build.gradle project

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio- Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146640/android-studio-program-type-already-present-com-google-android-gms-internal-me)

Comment: Would you please try to remove the `.gradle` file and then sync again. Hope this will solve.