# fails to build an (newly created) ejected expo project

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

I am trying to add react-native-firebase to a newly created expo project, I ejected the app successfully, but when I try to add the library the project fails to build and I get the following error

```
ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0.
1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[
15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.2.0.
```

I updated all firbase dependencies but it still fails, I then used this line to force stop the errors so I can at least build
`com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true`

the previous error is gone but I keep different errors. eg:

```
Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbk
```

platform: Ubuntu 19:04
expo: Latest
react-native-firebase: 5.2.5

**gradle (project) file**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    // classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    classpath 'de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:2.0.0'
    classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-devicefarm-gradle-plugin:1.3' // https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-gradle-plugin/releases
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    // For non-detach
    maven {
      url "$rootDir/maven"
    }
    // For old expoviews to work
    maven {
      url "$rootDir/versioned-abis/expoview-abi26_0_0/maven"
    }
    maven {
      url "$rootDir/versioned-abis/expoview-abi27_0_0/maven"
    }
    maven {
      url "$rootDir/versioned-abis/expoview-abi28_0_0/maven"
    }
    maven {
      url "$rootDir/versioned-abis/expoview-abi29_0_0/maven"
    }
    maven {
      url "$rootDir/versioned-abis/expoview-abi30_0_0/maven"
    }
    maven {
      url "$rootDir/versioned-abis/expoview-abi31_0_0/maven"
    }
    maven {
      url "$rootDir/versioned-abis/expoview-abi32_0_0/maven"
    }
    // For detach
    maven {
      url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expokit/maven"
    }
    maven {
      // We use a modified build of com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1. Explanation in maven-test/README
      url "$rootDir/maven-test"
    }

    maven {
      // Local Maven repo containing AARs with JSC built for Android
      url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist"
    }
    flatDir {
      dirs 'libs'
      // dirs project(':expoview').file('libs')
    }
    // https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5225#issuecomment-445739013
    maven { url 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    // Want this last so that we never end up with a stale cache
    mavenLocal()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle (app)**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'devicefarm'

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 27

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'expo.reactnative.test'
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0.0'
    ndk {
      abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
    }
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    // Deprecated. Used by net.openid:appauth
    manifestPlaceholders = [
        'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'host.exp.exponent'
    ]
  }
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize System.getenv("DISABLE_DEX_MAX_HEAP") ? null : "8g"
  }

  flavorDimensions 'remoteKernel'
  productFlavors {
    devKernel {
      dimension 'remoteKernel'
    }
    prodKernel {
      dimension 'remoteKernel'
    }
  }
  signingConfigs {
    debug {
      storeFile file('../debug.keystore')
    }
    release {
      storeFile file(System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH") ?: "release-key.jks")
      storePassword System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
      keyAlias System.getenv("ANDROID_KEY_ALIAS")
      keyPassword System.getenv("ANDROID_KEY_PASSWORD")
    }
  }
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      debuggable true
      ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }
  packagingOptions {
    pickFirst "**"
  }
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
  }
}

devicefarm {
  projectName System.getenv("DEVICEFARM_PROJECT_NAME")
  devicePool System.getenv("DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_POOL")
  executionTimeoutMinutes 40
  authentication {
    accessKey System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
    secretKey System.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
  }
}

configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r224109'
  }
}

// WHEN_PREPARING_SHELL_REMOVE_FROM_HERE

apply from: 'expo.gradle'

// WHEN_PREPARING_SHELL_REMOVE_TO_HERE

dependencies {
  implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.5.0'

  // Firebase dependencies
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
  // 
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

  // Our dependencies
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

  // Our dependencies from ExpoView
  // DON'T ADD ANYTHING HERE THAT ISN'T IN EXPOVIEW. ONLY COPY THINGS FROM EXPOVIEW TO HERE.
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.37.0'
  implementation('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.0') {
    exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
  }
  compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:3.1.1'
  implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
  implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'

  // Be careful when upgrading! Upgrading might break experience scoping. Check with Jesse. See Analytics.resetAmplitudeDatabaseHelper
  implementation 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.9.2'

  implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Compiler:2.2.1'
  implementation "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Core:2.2.1"
  implementation "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow:2.2.1"
  implementation "com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.53.0.0"
  implementation "com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.53.0.0"
  debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
  // debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta1'
  releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
  implementation 'com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:2.1.0'
  implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:1.4'
  implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
  implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
  implementation 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1'
  implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
  implementation 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.3.0'
  implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
  implementation 'net.openid:appauth:0.4.1'
  implementation('com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
  }
  implementation('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.11') {
    transitive = false
  }
  implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0'
  implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.5.1'

  implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.6.1'
  implementation 'expolib_v1.com.google.android.exoplayer:expolib_v1-extension-okhttp:2.6.1@aar'

  // expo-file-system
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0'

  // Testing
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
  // We use a modified build of com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1. Explanation in maven-test/README
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.azimolabs.conditionwatcher:conditionwatcher:0.2'

  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
  testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8'
  testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2-alpha1'
  testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2-alpha1'


  implementation('host.exp.exponent:expoview:32.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp-urlconnection'
  }




  api 'com.facebook.react:react-native:32.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-app-loader-provider:1.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-core:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-constants-interface:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-constants:2.0.1'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-errors:1.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-file-system-interface:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-file-system:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-image-loader-interface:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-permissions:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-permissions-interface:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-sensors-interface:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-react-native-adapter:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-task-manager:1.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-task-manager-interface:1.0.0'

  // Optional universal modules, could be removed
  // along with references in MainActivity
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-ads-admob:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-app-auth:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-analytics-segment:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-barcode-scanner-interface:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-barcode-scanner:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-camera-interface:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-camera:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-contacts:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-face-detector:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-face-detector-interface:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-font:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-gl-cpp:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-gl:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-google-sign-in:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-local-authentication:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-localization:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-location:2.0.1'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-media-library:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-print:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-sensors:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-sms:2.0.0'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-background-fetch:1.0.0'


}

// This has to be down here for some reason
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}

// This has to be down here for some reason
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Comment: Nothing in this answer helped?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146640/android-studio-program-type-already-present-com-google-android-gms-internal-me

Comment: unfortunately not. I updated all the dependencies in (app) `build.gradle` but I still get the same error

Comment: I seem to remember having this issue with `react-native-navigation` and solved by building through my terminal: `cd ./android && ./gradlew app:assembleDebug && ./gradlew installDebug` (run from root of project)

Comment: You probably already tried cleaning the project in Android Studio, right?

Comment: @DannyBuonocore yes I cleaned the project but the problem persist.
running that command returns `Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain`

Comment: This might help with that https://stackoverflow.com/a/29806323/2694189

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Add

```
maven {   // expo-camera bundles a custom
 com.google.android:cameraview   url
 "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven" }
```

to build.gradle at

```
 allprojects {
     repositories {
         mavenLocal()
        maven {
             // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
         }
         maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
             url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
         }
         maven {   // expo-camera bundles a custom com.google.android:cameraview   url
 "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven" }

         google()
         jcenter()
         maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
     } }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
maven {   // expo-camera bundles a custom   
    url("$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven") 
}
```