# Generating signed apk with android studio

Tags: android, apk

I have an error message in Android Studio when I tried to generate a new signed apk. The error is : "

---

**Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzd
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzd, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}**

---

Here is my gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fr.xyz.application"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 46
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id: 'c52d60a9-812a-42d2-9157-7d2e5d777803',
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

and my build.gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.11.1, 0.99.99]'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: update your dependencies

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50147103/5192105

Comment: @kam1234 is right. Simply update all your dependencies and make sure they correspond with the gradle version you are using.

Comment: how can I update all my dependencies ? Do I have to do it manually ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio- Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146640/android-studio-program-type-already-present-com-google-android-gms-internal-me)

Comment: I just updated the dependencies manually but then I got : " error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found"  and "error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found" and at the bottom I got "failed linking references"

Answer (score 0):

Use these dependencies :

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'{
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'{
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'{
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.x') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

Comment: This is not working, I got an error which says :'Could not find method com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'

Comment: Made some changes, try now.

Comment: Add this : classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2' in build.gradle(Project)

Comment: paste your gradle files here.