# React Native: Error while building project

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, react-native-fetch-blob

Initially, everything was working fine, I was trying to update the build:gradle and SDK versions

I am getting the following while building the project

```
Gradle sync failed: More than one variant of project :react-native-fetch-blob matches the consumer attributes:
            - Configuration ':react-native-fetch-blob:debugApiElements' variant android-aidl:
            - Found artifactType 'android-aidl' but wasn't required.
            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
            - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
            - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
            - Configuration ':react-native-fetch-blob:debugApiElements' variant android-classes:
            - Found artifactType 'android-classes' but wasn't required.
            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
            - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wa... (show balloon)
```

Below is the build.gradlew file of react-native-fetch-blob

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    //{RNFetchBlob_PRE_0.28_DEPDENDENCY}
}
```

I have no idea what's going on

looking forward for much need help

thank you

Comment: What is your `google-services` version?

Comment: Hey @MRFrhn thank you for your response, `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'`

Comment: i have changed `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2` to `2.3.3` in main `build.gradlew` file now i'm not getting that error, but how do i updrade the `build.gradlew` to new version without getting any errors

Comment: keep the gradle version, change google-services to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'` and try again. there seems to be an issue with 3.3.0 version

Comment: Thank you! that worked fine. and can I use `play-services:15.0.1` currently I am using 11.8.0.

Comment: Ok so I'll post it as an answer to be helpful for others too :)
I think you're ok to use that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with google-services 3.3.0

Change it to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'` and it should work fine.

Comment: ok now i'm getting this error, `Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2.
   Searched in the following locations:
   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom
   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.jar
   Required by:
   project :react-native-fetch-blob
   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (20s 292ms)`

Comment: Change gradle to 3.2.1

Comment: if use `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3` everything works fine