# com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement is missing in Google Play Services 15.0.0 and greater

Tags: android, google-play-services

Play Services uses a [new versioning scheme](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/versioning) starting with version `15.0.0`. Updating Play Services analytics to version `15.0.0` or greater produces a compile-time error in our app because the package `com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement` has been removed. `AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver` was previously in this package. We are using `AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver` in a `JobIntentService` to share the install referrer intent with Google Analytics and Firebase Analytics. The `JobIntentService` is being used to cope with Android O background restrictions and the work gets enqueued by a custom install broadcast receiver. The `JobIntentReceiver` calls `onReceive` for both `CampaignTrackingReceiver` and `AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver`. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver) for `AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver` has not been updated. Creating one `JobIntentReceiver` to handle both `CampaignTrackingReceiver` and `AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver`is necessary because it’s only possible to have one install receiver in the manifest with the `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` intent filter. Is there any way around this issue that will allow us to keep both install referrers?

Comment: What is this intended for? While you're at it, check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50150850/6143482)?

Comment: AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver and CampaignTrackingReceiver are required for Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your dependency tree is not being automatically filled in.

Make sure you have both firebase-analytics and firebase-analytics-impl.

Even better, use firebase-core. It will automatically pull in the dependencies.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-core/16.0.1

Comment: Barrett A - My project currently contains play-services-analytics and firebase-messaging. If I add firebase-core then the following error appears: 
"The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.0,16.0.0], [16.0.2,16.0.2]], but resolves to 16.0.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies." Removing play-services-analytics resolves that error but then the issue is that `CampaignTrackingReceiver` cannot be resolved.